# Applying R package spatstat functions to one-dim data?

Tags: r, dimensions, spatstat

Functions in spatstat are mainly made for 2-3-dim data analysis. Is there a good possibility to apply them to one-dim data?

- There is huge capability for class ppp in 2-dim.
- There is a very general class ppx for arbitrary dimensions - but this is the problem - only very few functions are available.
- Can I take a sledgehammer to crack a nut in inflating one-dim data to two-dim one and in the end projecting back to one-dim?
- Or should I better rewrite functions for one-dim (rpoispp, rmpoispp, ...)?

Comment: maybe all you need to do is `mat1d <- matrix(my.vector,nrow=1)`, or alternatively `dim(my.vector)<-c(1,length(my.vector))`

Comment: Thank you. But it's not a question of transforming a vector into a one-dim matrix. To produce an object of class `ppp` one needs two vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on which analysis you are doing. In general I would not recommend inflating one-dim data to two-dim data.

As you state the class `ppx` is general, but doesn't have many functions implemented for it yet. If you just need to simulate an unmarked Poisson point process in 1-dim you can use `rpoisppx`.

To have more functions available one solution could be to represent your data as a point pattern on a linear network (class `lpp`). Here is a crude example representing a section of 1-dim space as a line in the unit square and simulating a Poisson process on the line with intensity 10:

```
X <- ppp(x=c(0,1), y=c(.5,.5), window=square(1))
L <- linnet(X, edges=matrix(1:2,1,2))
Y <- rpoislpp(10, L)
```

Comment: Very nice! I changed the model by defining an object of `lpp`: `X` as above then `L <- linnet(ppp(x=c(0,1), y=c(.5,.5), window=square(1)), edges=matrix(1:2,1,2))` and to the end `lpp(X, L)`